# Block return until async call is finished Java?

Tags: java

```
public void method(){
   runAsyncFunction();
   return;
}
```

I am wondering how it would be possible to block and NOT return this function (`method`) until the `runAsyncFunction()` is complete. Is this possible in Java 8? I have read about Futures, but I am not too sure how they work yet.

Comment: What does `runAsyncFunction()` return? How does it let you know that it's completed its task?

Comment: Why do you call an asynchronous function, if you do not want to have it asynchronously?

Comment: I suggest you read this [awesome answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/748189/8075923) that explains what asynchronous/synchronous method really means.

Answer (score 0):

Why do you call an asynchronous function, if you do not want to have it asynchronously? For example Future only

See [JavaDoc Future](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html)

```
public void method(){
   FutureTask<String> future=
   new FutureTask<String>(new Callable<String>() {
     public String call() {
       return searcher.search(target);
   }});
   executor.execute(future);
   while(!future.isDone()){
       Thread.sleep(100);
   }
   return;
}
```